# Read HTML File in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dom

I have some files that were displayed in a browse and then I used File, Save As.. to place the text in a local file. The page has some scripting and it will not display properly in a WebBrowserControl on a WinForm. The problem appears to be scripts as the control displays "script error" dialogs. I don't really need to view the file but to just retrieve a few elements by ID.

The first block of code below does load the file into a local object, but only the first 4096 bytes. (Same happens if I use a WebBrowser resident on the form.)

The second block doesn't complain but the GetElementByID fails as the desired element is beyond the first 4096.

```
    Dim web As New WebBrowser
    web.AllowWebBrowserDrop = False
    web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
    web.Url = New Uri(sFile)

    Dim doc As HtmlDocument
    Dim elem As HtmlElement
    doc = web.Document
    elem = doc.GetElementById("userParts")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is there a better approach for a VB.Net WinForm project for loading an HTML document from which I can read elements?

---

I just went with string functions for the simple task at hand:

```
    Function GetInnerTextByID(html As String, elemID As String) As String
    Try
        Dim s As String = html.Substring(html.IndexOf("<body>"))
        s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(elemID))
        s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(">") + 1)
        s = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("<"))
        s = s.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "").Trim
        Return s
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function
```

I'd still be interested in a native VB.Net (non-ASP) approach. Or why the OP only loads 4096 bytes.

Comment: You can use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: True - but overly complex for my simple task of extracting a few elements by ID.

Comment: It has also a `document.GetElementById` method which is pretty simple. And it has no strange issues with scripts or bytes. Just load the document from web,file or plain string.

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack is complex because its solving the exact issues you're facing right now. Without it, your code will end up a mess itself and probably less efficient. I will never understand people's reluctance to bring a proven/tested third party library into their project.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead.

You: *"True - but overly complex for my simple task of extracting a few elements by ID."*

It has also a `document.GetElementbyId` method which is rather simple. And it has no strange issues with scripts or bytes. Just load the document from web, stream, file or from a plain string.

For example (web):

```
Dim document As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
Dim myHttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("URL"), HttpWebRequest)
myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compat ble; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
Dim streamRead = New StreamReader(CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse).GetResponseStream)
Dim res As HttpWebResponse = CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
document.Load(res.GetResponseStream(), True)

Dim node As HtmlNode = document.GetElementbyId("userParts")
```

or from file:

```
document.Load("Path")
```

or from string(f.e. a whole webpage in a html-file read by `File.ReadAllText`):

```
document.LoadHtml("HTML")
```